# Semantic UI - Dropdown Remote Content -Extra data

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, semantic-ui, dropdown

I've got a dropdown with semantic ui which gets the data with an api for example : city.

I've got also a input : postal code. I want that when a user select a choice in city the postal code is automatically entered.

I've got this answer from the api :

```
{
"success": true,
"results": [
  {
    "name"  : "Paris - 75000",
    "value" : "paris",
    "postal_code": "75000"
  },
  {
    "name"  : "Manhattan ",
    "value" : "manhattan",
    "postal_code": "10001"
  }
]}
```

So my question is how to use postal_code with semantic ui in order to fill the second input ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: What have you tried? Please post any HTML or JS that you might have tried. Also, you are missing a double quote at the end of  ```10001```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution : I use the search component and then with the callback onSelect(result, response) the result object contains the postal_code.

Thank you !